# DELETE FROM ... reporting syntax error at or near "."

Tags: database, postgresql, row, delete-row, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete just one data from my DB, but, when I write the command I keep getting that there's some syntax error, could you tell me where is the error?

This are the commands I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM database_userprofile WHERE user.username = 'some';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: DELETE FROM database_userprofile WHERE user.username = 'some'...

DELETE FROM database_userprofile USING database_user WHERE user.username="some";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ... database_userprofile USING database_user WHERE user.username=...
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: *always* include tour PostgreSQL version and any relevant table definitions. Explaining what you're trying to achieve so we don't have to guess helps too. Upvoting anyway this time because you *did* include full, exact command text and errors (thanks!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query doesn't make any sense.

```
DELETE FROM database_userprofile WHERE user.username = 'some';
                                       ^^^^
```

Where'd `user` come from? It isn't referenced in the query. Is it a column of `database_userprofile`? If so, you can't write `user.username` (unless it's a composite type, in which case you would have to write `(user).username` to tell the parser that; but I doubt it's a composite type).

The immediate cause is that [`user` is a *reserved word*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). You can't use that name without quoting it:

```
DELETE FROM database_userprofile WHERE "user".username = 'some';
```

... however, this query still makes no sense, it'll just give a different error:

```
regress=> DELETE FROM database_userprofile WHERE "user".username = 'some';
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM database_userprofile WHERE "user".username = 'so...
```

My wild guess is that you're trying to do a delete over a join. I'm assuming that you have tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id serial primary key,
    username text not null,
    -- blah blah
);

CREATE TABLE database_userprofile (
     user_id integer references "user"(id),
     -- blah blah
);
```

and you're trying to do delete with a condition across the other table.

If so, you *can't* just write `user.username`. You must use:

```
DELETE FROM database_userprofile
USING "user"
WHERE database_userprofile.user_id = "user".id
AND "user".username = 'fred';
```

You'll notice that I've double-quoted "user". That's because it's a keyword and shouldn't really be used for table names or other user defined identifiers. Double-quoting it forces it to be intepreted as an identifier not a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Due to documentation, the syntax for delete in PostgreSQL 9.1 is:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
DELETE FROM [ ONLY ] table [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    [ USING using_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

So you need to specify the "table_name" after DELETE command, not the "database_name".
You can delete data only if you are logged into the database.

You got
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
because in the WHERE section you can specify the target table or the tables in the usinglist.

Comment: Actually, the immediate cause is that `user` is a reserved word.

Answer (score -1):

You may also get this error when copy-pasting a query from Eclipse to pgadmin. Somehow, a strange symbol may be inserted. To avoid this error, paste it in a simple text editor first (like notepad), then cut it from there and paste it in pgadmin.