# cant delete data from postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, delete-row, sql-delete

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL, so maybe I'm getting some noob error I cannot recognize, so please, tell me why I cannot get this data deleted.

This is what is happening:

```
DELETE FROM userprofile WHERE user LIKE (SELECT User FROM User WHERE username LIKE 'testuser');
ERROR:  column "username" does not exist
LINE 1: ...file WHERE user LIKE (SELECT User FROM User WHERE username L...
```

As I'm using django user, I know that username does exists, so, how can I get it deleted?

Comment: So your `column "username" does not exist`. What exactly is your question? Table definition, PostgreSQL version?

Comment: I'm user django user, and username does exist, I want to know why it is doesn't getting deleted

Comment: The table definition would be **essential** to this question.

Comment: the table what? I'm self taught and rally new to PostgreSQL, in fact, I'm learning because in the job I have to use it, not because I've studied it

Comment: Then you really need to start by reading the basics in the manual. I provided some links.

Comment: @Sascuash Start with the PostgreSQL tutorial, then the PostgreSQL user manual. Both are IMO really good. As for table definitions: connect with `psql` and use `\d tablename`.

Comment: You seem to have basically re-posted this from http://stackoverflow.com/q/16985083/398670 . What's the deal? Also, why are you using `LIKE` not `=`? (Downvoted because you've basically copied this question to a new one, wasting everyone's time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are (stab in the dark for lack of information) you didn't think of lower-case names.

Start by reading [the manual about identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

What do you get for:

```
SELECT n.nspname, c.relname, a.attnum, a.attname
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relname ilike 'user'
AND    NOT a.attisdropped  -- no dropped (dead) columns
AND    a.attnum > 0        -- no system cols
ORDER  BY 1,2,3
```

Pay attention to capitalization of identifiers. Why? Follow the link to the manual above.

You also seem to be confusing the `name` of a column with a `value` stored in this column. The error message complains about the name, because it does not exist.

And you should never use [**reserved words**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `user` as identifiers to avoid problems like the one at hand. Those need to be enclosed in double-quotes at all times.

Comment: SELECT n.nspname, c.relname, a.attnum, a.attname
dbou78dfpdee3q-> FROM   pg_class c
dbou78dfpdee3q-> JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
dbou78dfpdee3q-> JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
dbou78dfpdee3q-> WHERE  c.relname ilike 'user'
dbou78dfpdee3q-> AND    NOT a.attisdropped
dbou78dfpdee3q-> AND    a.attnum > 0
dbou78dfpdee3q-> ORDER BY 1,2,3;
 nspname | relname | attnum | attname 
---------+---------+--------+---------
(0 rows)

Comment: @Sascuash: I you get 0 rows, there is no table like "user" or "User" or "USER" at all. Either way, never use `user` as table name, follow the links I provided.

Comment: Huh. Just wrote a quite similar reply to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16985083/398670 . I'm getting quite tired of people duplicating their questions...

Comment: @CraigRinger: Yeah, that's tiring. I need to remind myself, that many things I take for granted in my area are still new and bewildering for a newcomers - and be patient, that's the hard part for me. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It sometimes helps to remember what it was like formulating your first self-join or outer-join based query. "WTF is this inner/outer stuff?"

Comment: @CraigRinger: Ah the olden days! Back when I made my first JOIN with lego pieces .. or maybe not *that* long ago. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Huh. LEGO row blocks would actually be a pretty decent medium for explaining `INNER`, `LEFT OUTER`, `RIGHT OUTER` and `FULL OUTER` joins.